# Docker-compose with many (hundreds) of environments

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker to run a script which needs to be run in about 100 different environments.

What is the best practice to do that?

In similar situation but having less environments, I have tried several different approaches in the past, but I am not sure which is the best one.

1. I have written a script which loops through values and sets different environments. This runs in **one** container but is **sequential**.
2. I have written a script which loops through values, sets environments, and runs several processes each with its corresponding environment. This also runs in **one** container, and is **parallel**, but goes against 1 process per container principle. Additionally, I have noticed that when several processes run in the same container they fight for network and the **CPUs are waiting** for a long time.
3. I have written an ugly compose file where the only thing that changes is the `environment:` clause. This creates **multiple containers** but seems error prone due to lots of copy/pasting.

Is there such a thing like a loop in a compose file which will enable me to not have to copy/paste in a yml file?

Comment: What's the goal of having too many environments? What do you use the script for?

Comment: Maybe you should try the keyword `extends`, but it's supported up to version 2.1. It's not recommended in version 3.x of compose.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was:

1. I created a script which produces **docker-compose.${TYPE}.yml** with the different **commands** and **environments**
2. I had taken out *"the essentials"* in a **docker-compose.yml** file.
3. I start different types of services with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.${TYPE}.yml up -d`

In this way I:

1. **Automized** the creation of the different yml
2. I am running **one process per container**
3. I am running **containers in parallel**